# How can I solve this WEKA error evaluation model?

Tags: weka

After training a SMO using this code :

```
       Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(ClassData);
       SMO svm = new SMO();
       eval.crossValidateModel(svm, ClassData, 10, new Random(1));
       System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("\nResults\n\n",false));
       
       eval.evaluateModel(svm,ClassData);
```

I obtain this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.ReplaceMissingValues.input(weka.core.Instance)" because "this.m_Missing" is null
    at weka.classifiers.functions.SMO.distributionForInstance(SMO.java:1443)
    at weka.classifiers.evaluation.Evaluation.evaluationForSingleInstance(Evaluation.java:2208)
    at weka.classifiers.evaluation.Evaluation.evaluateModelOnceAndRecordPrediction(Evaluation.java:2246)
    at weka.classifiers.evaluation.Evaluation.evaluateModel(Evaluation.java:2122)
    at weka.classifiers.Evaluation.evaluateModel(Evaluation.java:689)
    at ClassCleanSMO.main(ClassCleanSMO.java:78)
```

As you can see ClassData works properly for crossevaluation but not for evaluation.
I think ClassData doesn't contain any missing value but 0 value only.
It gives me the same error evaluating a different TestSet.
It gives me the same error using J48 Classfier.

traininput2.arff is 198 + 1 attributes X 3600 numeric instances translated from a Matlab double array.
Classdata is originated from this code :

```
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ArffLoader;
import weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.NumericToNominal;
import weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.ClassAssigner;
import weka.filters.supervised.attribute.PartitionMembership;
import weka.filters.supervised.instance.ClassBalancer;
import weka.classifiers.Evaluation;
import java.util.Random;
import weka.classifiers.functions.SMO;


public class ClassCleanSMO {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

       // Loader
       ArffLoader loader = new weka.core.converters.ArffLoader();
       loader.setFile(new java.io.File("C:/Users/redmello/Desktop/traininput2.arff")); 
       Instances ClassData= loader.getDataSet();
       
       // FILTERS
       
       // Nun2Nominal
       NumericToNominal N2N = new weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.NumericToNominal();
       N2N.setInputFormat(ClassData);
       String[] options = new String[2];
       options[0] = "-R";
       options[1] = "last";  
       N2N.setOptions(options);
       ClassData = weka.filters.Filter.useFilter(ClassData, N2N);
       
       // ClassAssigner
       ClassAssigner MyClass= new weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.ClassAssigner();
       MyClass.setInputFormat(ClassData);
       String[] options3 = new String[2];
       options3[0] = "-C";
       options3[1] = "last";
       MyClass.setOptions(options3);
       ClassData =  weka.filters.Filter.useFilter(ClassData, MyClass);
       
       // PartitionMembership
       PartitionMembership PartMemb = new weka.filters.supervised.attribute.PartitionMembership();
       PartMemb.setInputFormat(ClassData);
       ClassData = weka.filters.Filter.useFilter(ClassData, PartMemb);
       
       // ClassBalancer
       ClassBalancer ClassBal = new weka.filters.supervised.instance.ClassBalancer();
       ClassBal.setInputFormat(ClassData);
       String[] options4 = new String[1];
       options4[0] = "10";
       ClassBal.setOptions(options4);
       ClassData =  weka.filters.Filter.useFilter(ClassData, ClassBal);
       
       // DATA MINING
       
       // crossValidationFoldMaker + J48
       
       Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(ClassData);
       SMO svm = new SMO();
       eval.crossValidateModel(svm, ClassData, 10, new Random(1));
       System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("\nResults\n\n",false));
       
       eval.evaluateModel(svm,ClassData);

    }

}
```

Some suggestion ?
I found nothing on the web.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The `crossValidateModel` method of the Evaluation class creates copies of the template classifier that you provide it with before training and evaluating these copies.

That means, that your instance of SMO, variable `svm`, has never been trained when you are trying to evaluate it on the full training set.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with that last evaluation call, as you already have the cross-validation statistics.

There are a few more issues with your code:

- The `setInputFormat` call needs to come after all the options have been set for a filter, as the filters will then initialize their internal data structures based on the currently set options. If you set the options afterwards, that will have no effect.
- When using filters, you should use them in conjunction with the `weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier` meta-classifier, to avoid any class information leakage when using supervised filters. If you have more than one filter, turn them into a filter pipeline using `weka.filters.MultiFilter`.

I've simplified your code to this:

```java
import weka.classifiers.Evaluation;
import weka.classifiers.functions.SMO;
import weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;
import weka.filters.Filter;
import weka.filters.MultiFilter;
import weka.filters.supervised.attribute.PartitionMembership;
import weka.filters.supervised.instance.ClassBalancer;
import weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.NumericToNominal;

import java.util.Random;


public class ClassCleanSMO2 {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    // load data
    Instances data = DataSource.read("C:/Users/redmello/Desktop/traininput2.arff");

    // make class attribute nominal
    // (only filter outside FilteredClassifier, as the Evaluation
    // class needs to be set up with correct class attribute)
    NumericToNominal n2n = new NumericToNominal();
    n2n.setOptions(new String[]{"-R", "last"});
    n2n.setInputFormat(data);
    data = Filter.useFilter(data, n2n);
    data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);

    // PartitionMembership
    PartitionMembership partMemb = new PartitionMembership();

    // ClassBalancer
    ClassBalancer classBal = new ClassBalancer();
    classBal.setOptions(new String[]{"-num-intervals", "10"});

    // combine filters
    MultiFilter multi = new MultiFilter();
    multi.setFilters(new Filter[]{
      partMemb,
      classBal,
    });

    // classifier
    // FilteredClassifier combines filter and base classifier
    SMO svm = new SMO();
    FilteredClassifier fc = new FilteredClassifier();
    fc.setClassifier(svm);
    fc.setFilter(multi);

    // cross-validate on data
    Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(data);
    eval.crossValidateModel(fc, data, 10, new Random(1));
    System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("\nResults\n\n",false));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to answer ! " I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with that last evaluation call, as you already have the cross-validation statistics. " . My last evaluation call "  eval.evaluateModel(svm,ClassData); " can be made for the testdata too and this has a meaning. Simply I want to evaluate the trained svm on the new dataset and to see the predictions. Now you say " That means, that your instance of SMO, variable svm, has never been trained when you are trying to evaluate it on the full training set." , I can't understand this! Do you mean this is the cause the error ?

Comment: For what about your code clarification and your new posted code I must  say it doesn't give me the same good result. Mine gives the same exact results I obtained using weka KnowledgeFlow. Thanks !

Comment: your : Correctly Classified Instances        1954               54.2778 %
Incorrectly Classified Instances      1646               45.7222 %
Kappa statistic                          0.0846
Mean absolute error                      0.4572
Root mean squared error                  0.6762
Relative absolute error                 91.6391 %
Root relative squared error            135.3803 %
Total Number of Instances             3600

Comment: mine : Correctly Classified Instances        3449.0941          95.8082 %
Incorrectly Classified Instances       150.9059           4.1918 %
Kappa statistic                          0.9162
Mean absolute error                      0.0419
Root mean squared error                  0.2047
Relative absolute error                  8.3837 %
Root relative squared error             40.9479 %
Total Number of Instances             3600

Comment: I obtain the same good results whitout ' eval.crossValidateModel(svm, ClassData, 10, new Random(1)); ' using ' SMO svm = new SMO();
    svm.buildClassifier(ClassData);
    Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(ClassData);
    eval.evaluateModel(svm, ClassData);
    System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("\nResults\n\n",false)); ' and now I have no error . But I can't use '  eval.evaluateModel(svm, TestData); ' because PartitionMembership create a very different scheme using Testdata.

Comment: Now I understood , " svm.buildClassifier(ClassData); " was missing and I can use CrossValidateModel too !!

Comment: You should never use the training set for evaluation, as this will give you overly optimistic results. Lazy methods, like IBk will always return 100% accuracy as they store the whole training data and can therefore predict the correct class. The point is to use unseen data for evaluation to see whether the model is any good (use weka.classifiers.rules.ZeroR as baseline). If you only have one dataset (instead of dedicated train/test sets) then you should use cross-validation.

Comment: PartitionMembership and ClassBalancer are supervised filters. Such filters can leak class information into datasets, changing how classifiers will perform, most likely reporting overly optimistic results (hence the difference between your results and mine). Generally, supervised filters should **never** be used outside a FilteredClassifier context. FilteredClassifier ensures that all data (train and subsequent test data) gets filtered according to the same filter setups. Filtering data separately, filters will get initialized differently and may generate incompatible data - as you encountered.

Comment: Isn't this the normal method in knowledgeFlow? How can you use a FilteredClassifier in KnowledgeFlow ? My good results are the direct translation of a .kf file with the same results. Thanks! * I cannot post images or files *

Comment: The FilteredClassifier is just another classifier in which you configure your base classifier and your filter, just like with my code example.